# Why don't I get InvalidCastException when casting enum to integer fails?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

```
public enum Animal
{
    Dog = 1,
    Cat = 2,
    Cow = 3
}

int animalID = 4;
if ((Animal)animalID == Animal.Dog) // does not throw exception
```

animalID can't be casted to `Animal`.
Why don't I get `InvalidCastException` when casting enum to integer fails?

Comment: Daniel what happens if you actually assign the cast to another object and check the value of the object after the assignment? you are just comparing with == wich does return a value but in fact is not really assigning anything...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting ints to enums in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758321/casting-ints-to-enums-in-c)

Comment: See this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618305/enum-casting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it's not an invalid cast.

The value you are casting is *out of range* for the enum (in this case) but it's not invalid.

As the approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong a cast from integer to enum is perfectly legal.

[Source - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is an intended behaviour and can be pretty useful.  Consider enums defined with the [Flag] attribute.

btw, this is a dupe of
[Casting an out-of-range number to an enum in C# does not produce an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618305/enum-casting)

more answers may be in there :)